# In Manim, how can I transform a fraction into the denominator of another fraction?

Tags: python, latex, manim

I'm using Manim Community v0.17.2, and I am trying to animate a fraction transforming into the denominator of another fraction. But I am not able to do a nice transformation.

In particular, I'm trying to transform 1-1/2 into 1-(1-1/2), but when I try to do it, the "2" from the first fraction has an ugly transformation.

I tried using the following code, dividing each fraction into sections to make a smooth transform effect between them.

```
frac_1 = MathTex("1-{1\\over","{2}}")
frac_2 = MathTex("1-{1\\over","{1-{1\\over","{2}}}}")
self.play(
            Write(frac_2[0]),
            ReplacementTransform(frac_1[0], frac_2[1]),
            ReplacementTransform(frac_1[1], frac_2[2])
        )
```

`Write(frac_2[0])` and `ReplacementTransform(frac_1[0], frac_2[1])` work as I expect, but `ReplacementTransform(frac_1[1], frac_2[2])` doesn't. It should just transform the "2" from the first fraction into the "2" from the second fraction, but it doesn't seem to recognize that it's transforming a "2" into another "2" and gives a weird and ugly transform effect, instead of a smooth shift and scaling effect.

How can I fix this?

Extra: I also want to know if it's possible to give my fractions the same style that `\\cfrac` has. I don't like the way fractions look with `\\over` or with `\\frac`, but if I try to use `\\cfrac` I'm not able to separate the numerator and denominator into different sections, which is something I'll need later in my project (that's why I'm using `\\over` instead).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: On Manim Community v0.13.1 (don't have time right now to install the newer version), I am seeing the same issue. What is really strange is that if I run your code with both instances of "2" replaced with "0" or "1" or "6" or "7" then it works as expected. The digits "5" and "9" don't work, but look better than "2", "3", "4", and "8". Also, I tried replacing "2" with "x" and with "y". Replacing with "x" does not work, but "y" does.

Comment: @j_v_wow_d the wya I "solved" it was by using FadeTransform instead of ReplacementTransform